# nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

My web panel's pages require a .htaccess file and since I'm now using Nginx, I have to convert the .htaccess rewrite to work for Nginx. I used an online converter http://winginx.com/en/htaccess and it gave me what to put in and I am receiving an error when restarting Nginx to save changes.

Original .htaccess rewrite:

```
Options -Indexes
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$ index.php?url=$1.$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ajax$ _res/ajax.php [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Conversion:

```
# nginx configuration
location = /favicon.ico {
}
autoindex off;
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/(.*)(\.)(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1.$3 break;
}
}
location = /ajax {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /_res/ajax.php;
}
```

Config file with conversion code:

```
# redirect from non-www to www 
# uncomment, save file and restart Nginx to enable
#server {
#            listen   80;
#            server_name domain.com;
#            return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
#       }

server {
# Cloudflare
set_real_ip_from 199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20; 
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

# ngx_pagespeed & ngx_pagespeed handler
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeed.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedhandler.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedstatslog.conf;


  # limit_conn limit_per_ip 16;
  # ssi  on;

  access_log /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/log/access.log combined buffer=32k;
  error_log /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/log/error.log;

  root /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public;

  location / {

# block common exploits, sql injections etc
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/block.conf;

  # Enables directory listings when index file not found
  #autoindex  on;

  # Shows file listing times as local time
  #autoindex_localtime on;

  # Enable for vBulletin usage WITHOUT vbSEO installed
  #try_files        $uri $uri/ /index.php;

  }

  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
  #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
}

# nginx configuration
location = /favicon.ico {
}
autoindex off;
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/(.*)(\.)(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1.$3 break;
}
}
location = /ajax {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /_res/ajax.php;
}
```

Error:

`[root@radio ~]# nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/domain.com.conf:65`

All in all, I'm not sure if I'm placing the code in the right spot or what. But as of now, I'm getting that error as shown above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `location` blocks are in the wrong place. They have to be inside a `server` block.

I recommend that you study nginx configuration much more closely, so that you understand the whole concept. Otherwise you will only get problems in the future.